# Clear all the items

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How do I refresh(start over) all data by pressing the refresh button? I tried `item.clear` and `refresh`, neither worked.

```
gvAdminResults.Refresh();
cmbCategory.Items.Clear();
cmbUsers.Items.Clear();
cmbTests.Items.Clear();
this.Refresh();
```

[image]

Comment: Any code to look at? Have you debugged your application?

Comment: What kind of grid is this?  Is it a [`DataGridView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

To clear data from a combo box:

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: nope...didn`t work...i need the index of the combobox i`m using it...by making it -1 it throws an error

Comment: Well, naturally you're going to need a reference to the actual combobox in the grid.

Comment: sir @RobertHarvey this answer will not clear all the data from the `comboBox` i know you knew that :)

Comment: Well, I can't figure out what you want, and neither can anyone else, so I'm going to go ahead and close your question.  If you can edit it to make it more understandable, cast a moderator flag to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You are using Data Binding I assume.  Whatever you are binding the control to ( a list or whatever).  You need to clear that List.

```
List<item> itemsBoundtoControl=new List<item>();
itemsBoundToControl.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the `BindingSource` to bind the data into your `DataGridView` you could use the [`.Clear Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.clear.aspx) of `BindingSource`

```
bindingSource.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

set the source to null.

```
item.DataSource = null;
```

I believe this should work.

As Areks pointed out this will only work when using a datasource.

Comment: Are you sure these statements are called? Have you set a breakpoint at these lines?

Comment: yes it does call them

Comment: This doesn't work because he's probably adding rows programatically rather than filling datasources.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the DataGridView rows:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
```

or clear the source:

```
dt_dataGridView1Source.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: Rows collection cannot be programmatically cleared when the DataGridView control is data-bound to anything else than an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion. that what i got

Answer (score 0):

For a final answer we need to know how you are populating your datagrid and comboboxes.

I suggest you to try:

```
gvAdminResults.Rows.Clear();
```

Comment: That will yield this error sometimes: "Rows collection cannot be programmatically cleared when the DataGridView control is data-bound to anything else than an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion."